# ionic 2 super tabs error while running ionic serve

Tags: ionic3

I am using ionic 3. The version of ionic2 super tabs package I use is 5.2.0 . I get the following error while I run ionic serve,

```
Property 'parent' in type 'SuperTabsComponent' is not assignable to the same property in base type 
            'NavigationContainer'. Type 'NavControllerBase' is not assignable to type 'NavController'. Types of property
            'config' are incompatible. Type
            'import("D:/finwisely/Mitra24/mitra24/node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/config/config").Config' is not 
            assignable to type 'import("D:/finwisely/Mitra24/mitra24/node_modules/ionic-angular/config/config").Config'.
            Types have separate declarations of a private property '_c'.
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

update package.json

```
"devDependencies": { "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.2", "typescript": "~2.6.2"}
```